# Material UI Select Input has line through it

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

When the label is shrunk, the label has a line through it.

[image]

```
 <FormControl sx={{ margin: 1, width: 230 }}>
    <InputLabel shrink id="appraisal-ordered-label">
    Appraisal Ordered
    </InputLabel>
    <Select
    labelId="appraisal-ordered-label"
    id="appraisal-ordered"
    value={property.appraisal_ordered || ""}
    label="Appraisal Ordered"
    onChange={(event) =>
        updateProperty("appraisal_ordered", event.target.value)
    }
    >
    <MenuItem value={"yes"}>Yes</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={"no"}>No</MenuItem>
    </Select>
</FormControl>
```

"@mui/material": "^5.11.14",

Comment: You need to also specify the `notched` property on `Select`.